# Is there any easy way to convert (CRD) CustomResourceDefinition to json schema?

Tags: kubernetes, visual-studio-code, redhat

Developing CRDs for Kubernetes, using VScode as an IDE. Want to provide autocompletion and Intellisense in IDE.

It needs a JSON schema to do so. I have a huge number of CRDs to support. I want to do it in an easy way to convert CRDs to JSON schema.

Comment: You could, in theory, extract the Open API schemas (AFAIK, a superset of JSON schemas) from a custom resource definition (`spec.versions[].schema.openAPIV3Schema`). https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/custom-resources/custom-resource-definitions/#validation
https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-yaml#associating-a-schema-in-the-yaml-file

Comment: There's also kubeval for CR validations, but it won't allow autocompletion. https://www.kubeval.com/#crds

Comment: Despite the fact that you were asking about a way to convert CRDs to json schema, I believe that answer from @nicovak covers the original intention for the question. Please consider accepting it as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can export the swagger definition (including your CRDs) of your Kubernetes server and then generate the json schema from the swagger export.

Create a proxy to your API server and export the swagger

```
kubectl proxy --port=8080
curl localhost:8080/openapi/v2 > k8s-swagger.json
```

Using [openapi2jsonschema](https://github.com/instrumenta/openapi2jsonschema) generate the json schemas

```
openapi2jsonschema -o "schemas" --kubernetes --stand-alone k8s-swagger.json
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have CRD IntelliSense thanks to [vscode-kubernetes-tools](https://github.com/vscode-kubernetes-tools/vscode-kubernetes-tools/) extension. It will fetch CRD from the active cluster. Here is the relevant merged [pull request](https://github.com/vscode-kubernetes-tools/vscode-kubernetes-tools/pull/924) for feature details.